# Populating a database iterating a directory and deep directory structure

Tags: php, database, algorithm, file, import

I have an import script for an image gallery to populate the database based on an "images"-directory. The populating works fine, after I finally figured out how to properly use RecursiveIteratorIterator. Unfortunately it doesn't take account of sub-subalbums.

```
<?php
$dir = "/home/photofoli/domains/dev.photofolio.local/public_html/photo";            
$ir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$album_id = 0;
$image_id = 0;

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $iterator) { 

    $realpath = $iterator->getRealPath();

    if ($iterator->isDir()) { 
        // Counting
        $numberofpictures = 1;
        $lastalbumid = $album_id;               
        $album_id++;

        // SQL
        $albumname = $iterator->getFileName();
        $addslashes = addslashes($albumname);
        $albumslug = str_replace(' ','-',$addslashes); $albumslug = strtolower($albumslug);             
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `photofoli_db`.`albums` (`name`, `id`, `path`, `album_id`, `image_count`, `slug`) VALUES ('$addslashes', $album_id, '$addslashes', '1', $numberofpictures, '$albumslug');";
        $this->Album->query($sql);
    }   
    else {
        // Counting
        $numberofpictures++;
        $image_id++;

        // SQL
        $imagename = $iterator->getFileName();
        $imagepath = $albumname.'/'.$iterator->getFileName();
        $addslashes = addslashes($imagepath);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `photofoli_db`.`images` (`path`, `album_id`, `description`, `id`) VALUES ('$addslashes', $album_id, '$imagename', $image_id);";
        $this->Image->query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

How can I adapt the script to allow for sub-sub-albums? I am thinking about saving $lastAlbumID or even counting the number of '/' in the full path, but something tells me I should ask some help to rethink the design of the script for this purpose.

Examples of paths:

```
/images/album1/test.jpg
/images/album1/test5.jpg
/images/album2/test.jpg
/images/album1/subalbum/test.jpg (this is a problem, because it's in a sub-sub directory)
```

*Disclaimer: The reason I use a script for repopulating the database is because it is quicker when uploading 300 files to re-run the script, than manually adding 300 new images.*

Comment: Using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` as you are should produce a 'flattened' array of all files and folders in the path to any depth, so your script should already be seeing the subalbums.

Answer (score 0):

You might include this piece of code into a function which accepts a directory path: whenever you find a subdirectory you can call this function recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
);
$map = array();
foreach ($ritit as $splFileInfo) {
    $dir = dirname($splFileInfo->getRealPath());
    $map[ $dir ][] = $splFileInfo->getFileName();
}

print_r($map);
```

It produces a map where the dir is the key, and the values are the filenames that are direct children of that dir.

It should be cake to loop over the resulting array, counting and inserting into the db.